# How to replace SQL Server file verification to table verification

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, pyodbc

Currently, on my company's MS SQL Server, there are csv files which are produced on the same VM as the SQL Server. They are imported on the database using procedures and verifications as T-SQL xp_fileexist and bulk insert [table] from [file.csv].

Due to security issue I am asked to change the flow of imported files using another new VM and it is forbidden to directly send those files to the SQL Server VM. The problem is that all the procedures running to verify the files are important and I was wondering what was the best way to keep everything working while respecting the new security rules.

What I tried is to use a python script on the new VM. I used pyodbc to read the files.csv and directly sent data to the SQL Server on the other VM. But then the procedures making files verifications won't work anymore.

Is there a better way to do it ? Hoping my explanations are clear. Thanks !

Comment: If you're using a push solution, why does the SQL Server instance need to verify the files exist at all?

Comment: There are more verifications, other procedures are called to insert logs, copy paste the file into zip for history, verify the number of rows. I would like to have as little impact as possible on all the procedures working on the file import. If you think my solution is adequate maybe the best to do is to remove all the verification procedures hoping it won't break the other things running

Comment: Why is *any* of that happening from SQL Server... The SQL Server host has nothing to do with zipping files. Sounds like your using SQL Server for a multitude of roles it shouldn't be. It's a database engine, it manages databases, not files...

Comment: I agree with you... previous people have made everything in TSQL without respecting any rule and now it's hard to manage everything as it dates back to 2014. I guess I just need to adapt the procedures (which will be a big pain)

Comment: Sounds like the procedures shouldn't exist; period.

Comment: There are hundreds of them and I expect to break everything removing them but yes gonna do my best. Thanks !

Comment: Yes, it's going to be a big job. If someone previously designed a lot of stuff badly, it's going to take a lot of effort to rewrite it from the ground. But using SQL Server as a generalized scripting engine is always going to be bad, and it will be worth the effort at the end

Comment: Adding on to what others are saying, it sounds like you're on the right path by divorcing the file management from the data management. As a word of encouragement, my guess is that the first couple of these will take a while as you figure out what to do but I'll bet that there will be a generalizable pattern that emerges. Stick with it!

Comment: Thanks for the support !